# Package UserService class does not exist in Android Studio?

Tags: android-activity, android-studio

I'm developing an app for the first time in android studio. I am developing it using the help from this link over here: [Code Project Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803688/Lets-create-the-Screen-Android-UI-Layout-and-Contr#login_activity_sub)

I'm using a package called UserService and somehow i'm getting the error that it does not exist.
So could someone tell me how to resolve this error. I searched google a lot but couldn't find any solution.

```
import com.bese3.nauman.citizen.data.User;
import com.bese3.nauman.citizen.data.service.UserService;
```

It cannot also resolve the symbol data.

And this is the direct link where they are using the UserService in the tutorial. [Direct Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803688/Lets-create-the-Screen-Android-UI-Layout-and-Contr#login_activity_sub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UserService that is mentioned in the example is a [part of the example application](https://github.com/varavut/code_project_android_tutorial_contest_article_4/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/vable/android/viewandlayoutlessons/data/service/UserService.java), not 3rd party dependency.

You can't just use it out of thin air. You can clone the example application and modify it, if you think that it is close to your needs.